# Debug Target Missing Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

When I try and run my c# program on visual studio i get an error saying 'Visual Studio can not start debugging bc the debug target (insert path) is missing'.
When I checked that path there were no files in that folder.

I have tried nearly every way on stack overflow but its not working, Ive rebuilt the project, and the solution, checked the properties file to make sure the PATH is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and test, and I think you can check if following option has been selected.

Right-click solution > Properties > Configuration Properties > Configuration > check the `Build` checkbox of your project > Apply > OK.

Beside, please also choose `Set as Startup Project` for your project which you’d like to debug.

[image]